# How to configure waffle to use automatic login?

Tags: tomcat, waffle

I've got a webpage on Tomcat 8.5 which uses Waffle 1.9.0 to handle single sign on.
On localhost it automatically logs me in but since I deployed it on a remote server, it sporadically asks me for credentials and tells me that the website is not secure. It's an internal application and I have no certificate for it.

Is there a way to configure waffle to always log in automatically without asking for credentials?

This is my filter in web.xml:

```
 <filter>
    <filter-name>SecurityFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>waffle.servlet.NegotiateSecurityFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>principalFormat</param-name>
      <param-value>fqn</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>roleFormat</param-name>
      <param-value>both</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>allowGuestLogin</param-name>
      <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>securityFilterProviders</param-name>
      <param-value>
        waffle.servlet.spi.NegotiateSecurityFilterProvider
        waffle.servlet.spi.BasicSecurityFilterProvider
    </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>waffle.servlet.spi.NegotiateSecurityFilterProvider/protocols</param-name>
      <param-value>
        NTLM
    </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>waffle.servlet.spi.BasicSecurityFilterProvider/realm</param-name>
      <param-value>WaffleFilterDemo</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SecurityFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two reasons, why you are seeing this issue.

1. The client has not done proper Browser configuration.
2. Client and Server are not in the same domain.

For the first issue, you need to do proper browser configuration so that the server is added as a trusted site in the client. For more details, follow this link:

https://github.com/Waffle/waffle/blob/master/Docs/ConfiguringBrowsers.md

For the second issue, just check if the client and server are on the same domain or not. Because if the client and server are not on the same domain the server and client can't identify each other.